# C# Threading.Timer not always triggering when in a windows Service Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, windows-services

Folks, I am implementing a routine in a Windows service .NET based, and am using a Threading.Timer task within

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
   base.OnStart(args);
   _startupTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(StartupAction, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

in my StartupAction i am defning a Threading.Timer as follows:

```
private void StartupAction()
{ 
    System.Threading.Timer infamousTimer;
    infamousTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(runMeEveryHour), null, new TimeSpan(0), new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
}
```

One would think that this is a no brainer, but for some reason it is not always working (works on some PCs but not on others).

Would anyone know what would be the culprit or the environment dependency?

Thanks

**When Timers go out of scope callbacks wont be triggered. See answers below**

Comment: Why use a task? Why not just start the threaded timer in `OnStart`? Granted your real use case may be more complicated and you've just simplified it, but what happens if you move it outside of the task?

Comment: @Lloyd true, I could do it less fancy but still why would that create a difference!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is in that you use a `Task` and create the timer entirely contained in the task action:

```
private void StartupAction()
{ 
    System.Threading.Timer infamousTimer;
    infamousTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(runMeEveryHour), null, new TimeSpan(0), new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
}
```

What I think is happening is once the `StartupAction` completes the timer goes out of scope and is disposed/GC'd.

Instead move the timer variable outside:

```
private Timer infamousTimer;

private void StartupAction()
{ 
    infamousTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(runMeEveryHour), null, new TimeSpan(0), new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
}
```

The advantage here is also in `OnStop` you can dispose of the timer cleanly.

Of course, why even do this in a `Task`? Seems overkill when just doing it in `OnStart` would work just as well.

I'd also like to point out that if all the service does is run a timer, you'd be better off with a scheduled task, but I'm making an assumption there.

See [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/428303) on why.

Comment: omg, that's true, it make sense. This is it, thanks for the extra info.

Answer (score 1):

When Timers go out of scope callbacks wont be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I think your StartupAction method is simply ending (the fact that it goes out of scope and get's garbage collected is a by-product, in my opinion).

You need to modify your StartupAction method to keep it alive.

Try adding something like: `while(true) { Thread.Sleep(1000); }` to keep the thread alive.

```
private void StartupAction()
{ 
    System.Threading.Timer infamousTimer;
    infamousTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(runMeEveryHour), null, new TimeSpan(0), new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
    while(true) { Thread.Sleep(1000); } //this is the simplest logic to keep the thread alive
}
```

Comment: You're keeping a thread tied down needlessly when all you need to do is move where the timer is referenced.